# TypeError: unsupported operand

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time and get this error when trying to operate.

## Error: TypeError: file  line 57: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

What am i missing here so i can make an option for users to select a certain amount of joint chains to be distributed into a circle?

```
def DistributeRad_Chain(): # this is the command option to distribute the chains in a circle if desired 
   radius= cmds.floatSliderGrp("Radius", query= True, value= True)
   sel= cmds.ls(sl= True)
   if not sel:
       print ('No chain was selected! You need to select 2 chains to start!')  
       return

   angleBetween = 6.28/ sel
   currentAngle = 0.0    

   for i in range(sel):
       currentAngle = angleBetween * i
       cmds.move(math.sin(currentAngle)*radius, 0, math.cos(currentAngle)*radius, absolute=True)
```

Comment: What did you not understand from `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'`? `6.28` is of type `float`, `sel` is of type `list`.

Comment: @stovfl Thanks, I'm confused about how it wouldn't be supported at all. Is there a better way to reword what I'm defining? It's supposed to take pre-created joint chains and select the 1st of each of the chains to be distributed evenly in a circle.

Comment: ***"select the 1st of each of the chains"***: Probably you need `sel[0]`? I don't know anything about `sel= cmds.ls(sl= True)`. [Edit] your question and show the instantiation of `cmd`, which type it is. Also do `print(sel)`, and show the output.

Comment: @stovfl That worked! i was missing that sel[0] variable. Thanks!